# Ext JS 3: How to copy a dynamically-generated treepanel?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3, treepanel

I have a **dynamically-generated** Ext.tree.TreePanel in Ext 3.3.1. It looks like this:

```
-root
    -fruit
        -apple
    -vegetable
        -carrot
```

I need to make a **duplicate/copy of this tree**. I understand that the ids will be different and that's fine, but I want the text and the structure to be the same.

My current idea is to recursively go through and node-by-node create a new tree. **Is there a faster way?** NOTE: Someone very helpfully suggested cloneConfig(), but my understanding is that it will not capture a dynamically-generated tree. Is this confusion on my part?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a clone of any ExtJS component's configuration using cloneConfig() function.

See the `Ext.Component` documentation: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-cloneConfig

Comment: Thank you - this answers the question I asked but unfortunately not the one I meant. I have a **dynamically generated** tree. To be fair, I'll give you credit for answering but keep the question open.

Comment: Why not? You can clone your store not only tree. Or explain what you mean in "dynamically-generated".

Comment: In Ext 3, trees don't have stores. My tree is dynamically generated by recursive calls to a web service. I'm trying to clone its current state rather than having to re-do all those calls.

Comment: Add your code please. May be we can clone only root, otherwise we can clone all tre recursively.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't add my code, I'm working for a private company.